# Spotipy throws 404 when retrieving song data

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify, spotipy

**EDIT 2: As @ximzend said, `spotipy` has moved to `playlist_items` instead of `playlist_tracks`**

**EDIT 1: In the process of moving to a `curses` interface, I changed the progress bar to a `tqdm` one (rather than `rich`), and that seemed to solve my problem. I did also upgrade `spotipy` (after it started working) but no change was needed in the API code ¯( ツ )/¯ so idk if `rich` was breaking the API req somehow or whatever**

**Thought I would put this here to help anyone in the future ツ**

---

---

`Spotipy` throws this error when trying to retrieve data about tracks in a playlist

```bash
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url:
```

The error is thrown on the line below, specifically the `self.sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_uri)['items']` part (The `progress.track` is a progress bar for the loop from [rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich/))

```
for song in progress.track(self.sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_uri)['items'], description='Listing songs...'):
```

Full traceback is:

```bash
HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/4wi8hpuh4oyjtivbzk3k9n/tracks with Params: {'limit': 100, 'offset': 0, 'fields': None, 'market': None, 'additional_types': 'track'} returned 404 due to Not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\projects\youtusic\youtusic-env\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 245, in _internal_call
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "T:\projects\youtusic\youtusic-env\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/4wi8hpuh4oyjtivbzk3k9n/tracks?limit=100&offset=0&additional_types=track

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t:\projects\youtusic\main.py", line 132, in <module>
    main()
  File "t:\projects\youtusic\main.py", line 119, in main
    track_list = obj.sp_get_tracks(playlist_uri)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "t:\projects\youtusic\youtusic.py", line 104, in sp_get_tracks
    for song in progress.track(self.sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_uri)['items'], description='Listing songs...'):
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "T:\projects\youtusic\youtusic-env\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 657, in playlist_tracks
    return self.playlist_items(playlist_id, fields, limit, offset,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "T:\projects\youtusic\youtusic-env\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 681, in playlist_items
    return self._get(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "T:\projects\youtusic\youtusic-env\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 297, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "T:\projects\youtusic\youtusic-env\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 267, in _internal_call
    raise SpotifyException(
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 404, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/4wi8hpuh4oyjtivbzk3k9n/tracks?limit=100&offset=0&additional_types=track:
 Not found., reason: None
```

The code I was using was as follows:

```py
def sp_get_tracks(self, playlist_link: str) -> list:
        '''
        Uses [spotipy](https://pypi.org/project/spotipy/) to retrieve
        a list of songs in the playlist provided. Returns a list to be
        used with `grab_yt_links`
        '''

        playlist_uri = playlist_link.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
        song_titles = []

        for song in progress.track(self.sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_uri)['items'], description='Listing songs...'):

            track_name: str = song['track']['name']
            artist_name: str = song['track']['artists'][0]['name']

            track_name = track_name.replace(' ', '+')
            artist_name = artist_name.replace(' ', '+')
            
            song_titles.append(f'{artist_name}+{track_name}')

        return song_titles
```

It should returns a list of all the songs (and artists) in the playlist. (The `progress.track` is a progress bar for the loop from [rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich/)). The `404` confuses me because my network connection is fine and I am able to perform Google searches etc

Additionally, the playlist only has 19 songs in so should be resticted by the limits I have read elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because Spotify made a code breaking change to its API.
SpotiPy has fixed this issue by releasing an upgrade.
To install this upgrade, open a command prompt and run `pip install spotipy --upgrade`.
After the upgrade, you need to use `playlist_items(playlist_id, fields=None, limit=100, offset=0, market=None, additional_types=('track', 'episode'))`.  `playlist_tracks` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I won't mark it as the accepted answer however as I changed the progress bar to a `tqdm` one (rather than `rich`) as I moved to a `curses` interface, and that seemed to solve my problem? I have also upgraded `spotipy` after it started working but no change was needed in the API code ¯\( ツ )/¯.  I also believe you have misread my code (I was read song titles not adding to a playlist) so I don't know if your solution would have affected my code - Thanks anyways though

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Both adding and getting tracks are changed, and switched them around I guess. I've changed my answer.

Comment: `Both adding and getting tracks are changed` ah ok, thanks for the info. Doing `sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_uri)['items']` seems to work fine but does throw a warning, will switch over now